# Unable to detect the EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID with DURATION tag in HLS on AVPlayer, iOs?

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming

We are playing a HLS stream with the help of AV player and trying to read HLS manifest. We are able to detect majority of the tags however player is not detecting the `EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID` with `DURATION` tag ie

```
#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="aba74c45-e963-45bf-8171-1f910c33f64a",DURATION=32.44
```

Where as, the other `#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID` has been detected at the beginning of the manifest.

```
#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="aba74c45-e963-45bf-8171-1f910c33f64a",START-DATE="2022-03-10T13:18:15.179Z",PLANNED-DURATION=15,X-AD-ID="9858"
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
```

We are using the AVPlayers metadata collector delegate method to detect the metadata

```
 func metadataCollector(_ metadataCollector: AVPlayerItemMetadataCollector,
                           didCollect metadataGroups: [AVDateRangeMetadataGroup],
                           indexesOfNewGroups: IndexSet,
                           indexesOfModifiedGroups: IndexSet) {}
```

We are not able to detect the `EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID` with `DURATION` tag with the delegate used above
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example

```
#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="aba74c45-e963-45bf-8171-1f910c33f64a",DURATION=32.44
```

does not contain `START-DATE`. This attribute is REQUIRED. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216#section-4.3.2.7